# Android: Correct Way to Change Launcher Activity (Read Fully)

Tags: android, android-activity, default, launcher

I'm facing the following issue. I have an app with an established user base, and I wanted to change my default launcher activity for the app.

The problem happens only for some users that updated the app via Google Play. Problem does not occur when running via Android Studio.

The problem comes into play with some of the users' Launchers on their phones. After they update the app, and when they try to open the app from their homescreens some users get "Error app not installed" or "Activity does not exist" errors.

It seems that on some users' devices, the OS launcher adds additional information about the activity name and this causes an issue after they update the app.

What's the correct way to change the launcher activity in order to avoid the problem I described above? This is quite an issue as a lot of non-techy users just uninstall the app.

- Previously .TabHostActivity was set as Launcher/Main
- After making .SplashActivity as Launcher/Main and rolling out the update to Google Play, some users started receiving "App not installed" error when opening the shortcut from their homescreen. App still works if they open it via App Drawer, but the shortcut on the homescreen gives this error.

Code:

```
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".TabHostActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
```

Comment: Show your current code

Comment: not sure about the exact problem, maybe try rebuilding the project after cleaning it.

Comment: Maybe you are not finishing activity or clearing activity stack when back button is pressed.

Comment: All - please note this happens only in production with some users.

Comment: You're not running into [the ages-old problem where the way the installer runs your app means that you get both the old version and the new version running simultaneously, if your app was already running](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5277), are you? Strikes me that what might be happening is that the installer installs the new version, then launches the currently-running instance of the *old* version, but with the new SplashActivity, that doesn't exist in it...)

Comment: I do not believe that a 2nd version of the app gets installed. The problem seems to be with shortcut only.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make TabHostActivity Launcher activity again.
2. In TabHostActivity at first check if it has been opened from SplashActivity (You can add a flag in the intent while starting the TabHostActivity from SplashActivity and check the same flag in TabHostActivity)
3. If  TabHostActivity has not been opened from SplashActivity, then redirect to SplashActivity.
4. All of the above should be coded before any other code in OnCreate of TabHostActivity.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. Do you call it before 'super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);' in onCreate or after.

Comment: Yes better to call it before.. Not much difference calling after though.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to be able to reproduce & confirm the issue before I upload to GooglePlay, but this is really hard to track. Any idea which launchers cause this?

Comment: No Idea.. You should ask one of your users facing this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of them are not tech savvy. Going to download top 5 launchers on GPlay and play around to see what happens. Will report my findings..